# Binding multiple DataSources to a single ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a database with two tables, `User` and `Image`.

`User` contains the fields ID (Primary Key) and Username
`Images` contains the fields `ID` (Primary Key), `UserID` (Foreign Key linked to `User.ID`), and ImageTitle

I have a ListView which contains ASP controls for these values

```
<h1><%#Eval ("ImageTitle") %></h1>
<h4 id="authorText">Uploaded by <%#Eval ("UserID") %></h4>
```

In my code behind class, I have this code to bind the data:

```
DataClasses1DataContext PiccyPic = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var images = from i in PiccyPic.Images
                     select i;

        lvwImages.DataSource = images;
        lvwImages.DataBind();
```

Now this works fine for when I want to retrieve values from the images table, but as you can see above I have "Uploaded by" and then the user ID, where I need to have the username.

What I'm asking is, how would I bind both the `User` and the `Image` table to the same listview, so I can access properties from both tables?

Bare in mind that seeing as both tables use an `ID` value as their primary key, it needs to know which table's ID column I'm referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a  join.

There's not enough information in the question to fully answer for you, but you should be able to figure out the syntax from this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx

I suspect the new query would look something like this, but without knowing how your classes are set up it's hard to say.

```
var images = from i in PiccyPic.Images
join user in PiccyPic.Users on i.UserId equals user.Id
select new { property1 = i.Property1, property2 = user.Property2, etc. }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Charles. I've made a join with the following code: `var images = from i in PiccyPic.Images
                         join user in PiccyPic.Users on i.UserID equals user.ID
                         select i;`

Now I just need to know how I reference that in my aspx page. Usually I would just do <%#Eval ("ID") %> but how do I let it know which table to look in? doing i.ID doesn't work.

Comment: Ah sorry, should be able to bind them using the alias you used in the initializer. It shouldn't really care which table the data come from, it's using an object for your data now.  So if you wanted to bind to property2 which was initialized from the Users table in my original guess you should be able to just use: <%#Eval("property2") %>.  Sorry I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign two datasources to a ListView. Therefore it is your responsibility to collect the two sources of data into on result set. You can use Stored Procedure or C# code to create one Dataset with Two Dataset. Here is example with Stored Procedure, if you need c# code then let me know

You can create the stored procedure(Join SQL Query) which return the single DataTable with Field

SELECT USer.UserID, UserName, ImageId, ImageTitle
FROM USer Inner join Images
ON user.userid = images.userid

then Use this datatable as DataSource for ListView